# Allow alpha characters, space, dash, apostrophe and length <= 50

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write regular expression that allows alpha characters, space, dash, apostrophe and length 50. So far I have this:

```
/^([A-Za-z\s].{1,50})$/
```

I'm not sure where I should place the code for dash and apostrophe. If anyone can help pleases let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem in the title. BTW, did you mean "length 50" or "length **up to** 50"?

Comment: @torazaburo What to explain? Everything is explained already and answer is below.

Comment: If you don't want advice, fine. Just consider, people click through to your question based on the title. It would be in your interest to make the title actually describe the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
/^[A-Za-z '-]{1,50}$/
```

or

```
/^[A-Za-z\s'-]{1,50}$/
```

When you use `\s` instead of  a space, you will allow any whitespace.

The apostrophe can be placed anywhere inside the character class (so as not to ruin the ranges), and the hyphen at the start/end of the character class does not need to be escaped.

If you use `{1,50}` [limiting quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), it means you allow 1 to 50 chars of the type specified in the character class. If you allow exactly 50 chars, use `/^[A-Za-z\s'-]{50}$/`. If you use just `+` instead, you will allow 1 or more characters.

Comment: Do I need + in this case? I'm trying to understand in which case I need plus and where do not.

Comment: *If you use just `+` instead, you will allow 1 or more characters.*

Comment: Is it better to use \s or just space in the character class?

Comment: Yeah `+` is the same as saying `{1,}` - at least one, possibly infinite. For reference, `*` is also the same as `{0,}`

Comment: @espresso_coffee as for the space vs `\s` - depends, the latter will allow, for example, tab characters and newlines as well as other whitespace characters. If you really _only_ want space, then you can use that.

Comment: It is up to you, just `\s` matches more than a regular space. Acc. to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions),  `\s` matches `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your answer and the time to explain everything!

Comment: How I can check if my field is [A-Za-z0-9] or blank and length is between 1 and 100 characters? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, this sounds unclear. `/^([A-Za-z0-9]{1,100}|\s*)$/` if you want to match a string that has 1 to 100 alphanumeric symbols OR 0 or more whitespaces (empty string included).

Comment: My filed length should not be greater than 20 characters. Filed type alpha or numeric characters 0-9, A-Z or blank.

Comment: No idea what you mean, try [`/^([A-Z0-9\s]{1,20})?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/5g4IQg/1)